# How to write tables in columns layout with ItextSharp

Tags: itext

I'm writing a report with itextsharp with tables organized horizontally in groups of four, but all tables appears one beneath the other vertically. How can I write each table NEXT to the other?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways that you can accomplish this. The first is to create a 4 column outer table and add your tables to the cells within that table. The second way is to just fix the width of each table and use the `PdfPTable` instance method `WriteSelectedRows()` to write your tables at exact x,y coordinates. [See my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590071/itextsharp-adjust-2-elements-on-exactly-one-page/7601244#7601244) for how to do the latter.