# iTextSharp: How to find the first and second row height in a table?

Tags: c#, itext

I want to get the first and second column height to know if I need to call `document.NewPage()` or not. But, I can't find a way to do this without adding the table to the document.

Example:

```
PdfPRow firstRow = new PdfPRow(cells1.ToArray());
table.Rows.Add(firstRow);
PdfPRow secondRow = new PdfPRow(cells2.ToArray());
table.Rows.Add(secondRow);

float h1 = table.GetRowHeight(0), h2 = table.GetRowHeight(1);

if (currentY - h1 - h2 < 30) document.NewPage();

document.Add(table);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590071/itextsharp-adjust-2-elements-on-exactly-one-page/7601244#7601244). Basically, you can't know the dimensions of a table until it renders. However, you can render the table to a document that you just throw away and then re-render it later.

Comment: Wonderfully detailed anf helpful answer

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, so +1. And already marked as answered, but...

> "But, I can't find a way to do this without adding the table to the document."

It **is** possible. Wrap the `PdfPTable` in a `ColumnText` object and take advantage of the [**ColumnText.Go()**](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.html#go%28boolean%29) overload to get the total height of any arbitrary/number of rows you want **without** adding the `PdfPTable` to the `Document`. Here's a simple helper method:

```
public static float TotalRowHeights(
  Document document, PdfContentByte content, 
  PdfPTable table, params int[] wantedRows) 
{
  float height = 0f;
  ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(content);
// respect current Document.PageSize    
  ct.SetSimpleColumn(
    document.Left, document.Bottom, 
    document.Right, document.Top
  );
  ct.AddElement(table);
// **simulate** adding the PdfPTable to calculate total height
  ct.Go(true);
  foreach (int i in wantedRows) {
    height += table.GetRowHeight(i);
  }
  return height;
}
```

And a simple use case tested with 5.2.0.0:

```
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, STREAM);
  document.Open();
  PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
  for (int i = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
    table.AddCell(i.ToString());
  }
  int[] wantedRows = {0, 2, 3};
  document.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format(
    "Simulated table height: {0}",
    TotalRowHeights(document, writer.DirectContent, table, wantedRows)
  )));
// uncomment block below to verify correct height is being calculated
/* 
  document.Add(new Paragraph("Add the PdfPTable"));
  document.Add(table);
  float totalHeight = 0f;
  foreach (int i in wantedRows) {
    totalHeight += table.GetRowHeight(i);
  }
  document.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format(
    "Height after adding table: {0}", totalHeight
  )));
*/
  document.Add(new Paragraph("Test paragraph"));
}
```

In the use case rows 1, 3, and 4 are used, but only to demonstrate any combination/number of rows will work.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you set the width of the table, table.GetRowHeight(0) will always return zero.

```
// added
table.TotalWidth = 400f;     
//
PdfPRow firstRow = new PdfPRow(cells1.ToArray());

table.Rows.Add(firstRow);
PdfPRow secondRow = new PdfPRow(cells2.ToArray());
table.Rows.Add(secondRow);

float h1 = table.GetRowHeight(0), h2 = table.GetRowHeight(1);

if (currentY - h1 - h2 < 30) document.NewPage();

document.Add(table);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do this:
Create the table at first.

```
    this.table = new PdfPTable(relativeColumnWidths);
    this.table.SetTotalWidth(absoluteColumnWidths);
    this.rowCells.Clear();
```

You may now fill the List with table cells:

```
    Paragraph pText = new Paragraph(text, this.font);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(pText);
    this.rowCells.Add(cell);
```

When you are ready to create the new row:

```
    PdfPRow row = new PdfPRow(this.rowCells.ToArray());
    this.table.Rows.Add(row);
```

This is nothing special. But if you now set the table width again, you are able to calculate the row height properly:

```
    this.table.SetTotalWidth(this.table.AbsoluteWidths);
    this.rowCells.Clear();
    float newRowsHeight = this.table.GetRowHeight(this.table.Rows.Count - 1);
```

If the row is not fitting your conditions you can simply remove it from the rows collection of the table. The total height of the table will be calculated properly also.